# Удалить повторные элементы из коллекции

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции, производительность, java-stream

Допустим, у меня есть коллекция, в которой миллион элементов (Double). Необходимо удалить все повторные элементы.
Из дубликатов нужно оставить последний элемент.
Например для `{5,1,5,3,2}` вывод должен быть:

```
{1,5,3,2}
```

Comment: Идите по коллекции с конца в начало и используйте хешсет

Answer (score 0):

Для результата нужно использовать `LinkedHashSet`, который сохранит порядок вставки элементов.

При итерации по входной коллекции нужно удалить существующий элемент и вставить его опять в новую позицию:

```java
public static <T> Set<T> keepLastDupes(Collection<T> data) {
    Set<T> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (T item : data) {
        if (result.contains(item)) {
            result.remove(item);
        }
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(5, 1, 5, 3, 2);

Set<Integer> result = keepLastDupes(data);

System.out.println(result);
// -> [1, 5, 3, 2]
```

---

При использовании Stream API понадобится кастомный коллектор, который можно получить при помощи [`Stream::collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```java
public static <T> Set<T> keepLastDupes(Collection<T> data) {
    return data
        .stream()
        .collect(
            LinkedHashSet::new, 
            (acc, item) -> { 
                if (acc.contains(item)) acc.remove(item);
                acc.add(item);
            }, 
            (acc1, acc2) -> acc1.addAll(acc2)
        );
}
```